# What is minimum MacOS version to decrypt external Mac hard disk encrypted through Finder?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, encryption

If you want to encrypt and password protect an external Mac HD/SSD and don't want to reformat it (because, perhaps, it already has data on it), one can use [this technique](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/protect-your-mac-information-with-encryption-mh40593/mac), which involves right-clicking in the Finder and letting the Mac encrypt the disk. However, with reference to this technique, Apple says

> WARNING: When you encrypt a disk or other media, the disk format is
> converted to the APFS format and then encrypted. Macs with older
> versions of macOS that don’t support the APFS format are not able to
> read the device’s data. Consider whether you need to connect the media
> to a Mac with an older version of macOS before you encrypt the data.
> You can also update your other Mac to the latest version of the macOS
> that supports the APFS format.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System), APFS was developed for MacOS Sierra, but I recall reading somewhere that to encrypt/decrypt using this encryption technique one needs High Sierra.  Can anyone clarify?

I suppose -- as someone suggested in a comment -- that I can test the process out with a pen drive.  If it works on the Mac, it works.  One issue is that it will be encrypted on a newer Mac, with a newer MacOS, and I will not have access to that Mac to test the process.  I don't know if encrypting on a newer Mac OS version and then decrypting on an older one makes any difference, but I wanted to find out all I could about the process before moving ahead.

Comment: This is rather broad as it includes several questions at once, and lacks some research (the first version of macOS supporting APFS is a Wikipedia lookup away, you can also easily test it yourself with any USB stick formatted to APFS).

Comment: Thanks.  I found the relevant Wikipedia article, which says "MacOS Sierra", but I recall reading somewhere "High Sierra".  The issue with testing it is the disk will be encrypted on a newer machine in one location, and will be decrypted on an older machine, with an older MacOS version, in another.  I'm just trying to make sure that process will work, without being able to test it fully beforehand.

Comment: Create a VM and test through that on your original machine